# ¿Cómo agrego nuevos registros a FireBase RealtimeDatabase desde mi app Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, xml

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para android que recoje el mensaje de un usuario y lo sube a una base de datos en FireBase, para luego ser consultada más adelante de forma aleatoria en cualquier momento del día y mostrar el mensaje registrado en la aplicación.

Mi problema radica en que no sé cómo puedo agregar nuevos registros a FireBase sin que se sobreescriba el único registro que he logrado hacer. Ya que al intentar insertar nuevos registros se sobreescribe el que ya tengo.

Intenté comparar una variable id con la ruta del id del mensaje en FireBase, pero la ruta simplemente no cambia...

Esta es mi Clase Main y es la única clase Java que he creado

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int id = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final EditText mensaje = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mensaje);
    ImageButton enviar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnviar);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            agregarDatos(mDatabase, id, mensaje.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}

// Escribir en la base de datos
public void agregarDatos(DatabaseReference mDatabase, int id, String mensaje) {
    String idMsg = "/" + Integer.toString(id);

    while(idMsg.equals(mDatabase.child("mensajes").child(idMsg).toString())) {
        int nuevoId = id;
        nuevoId++;
        idMsg = "/" + Integer.toString(nuevoId);
        Toast.makeText(this, "En ciclo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        mDatabase.child("mensajes").child(idMsg).child("mensaje").setValue(mensaje);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fuera de ciclo. id de mensaje: " + idMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, mDatabase.child("mensaje").child("0").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Y por si es necesario dejo tambien mi código XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
    android:text="Breathe"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="64sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/pacifico"
    android:text="Deja un lindo mensaje para alguien."
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mensaje"
    android:layout_width="267dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_round"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:maxLines="5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonEnviar"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rounded"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mensaje"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leerBreathes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="- o -"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonEnviar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leerMas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
    android:text="Leer Breathes"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/leerBreathes" />
```

Además tambien dejo una captura de las rutas de la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente sería una base de datos pequeña con una tabla "mensajes" que guarde datos de ID del mensaje y el mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema estaría en mi clase Java en la cual no logro incrementar el id del mensaje de forma dinamica para que el mensaje se guarde como un nuevo registro en lugar de sobreescribir el mensaje de un id determinado.

Comment: No se entiende mucho lo que quieres hacer. Lo primero que debes tener claro es qué estructura quieres en tu base de datos y a partir de ahí adaptar el código a esa estructura. Eso no queda claro en la captura de tu base de datos ni en tu código. Sugiero que pulses en [edit]  y aclares ese punto, el cual es fundamental.

Comment: Para agregar nuevos registros sin que se sobrescriba uno existente es necesario que alguno de los nodos del árbol sea distinto a los ya existente; pero es necesario que tengas claro como va a ser tu Base de Datos en Firebase ya que en el ejemplo no se ve claro como quieres que sea la estructura de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

Primero veo que se sobreescribe por que hace referencia al mismo mensaje.
Hace lo siguiente :
Crea un push

```
String push=mDatabase.child("mensajes").child(idMsg).child("mensaje").push().getKey();
```

Luego lo implementas así :

```
mDatabase.child("mensajes").child(idMsg).child("mensaje").child(push).setValue(mensaje);
```